# Cheat activated

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, compression

### Background

The game [Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto:_San_Andreas) went down in history also thanks to its wide selection of cheats. They're almost 90 and anyone who has ever touched this game, no doubt has tried them all!
One cheat is activated (on PC) typing in-game a secret keyword, and then boom, a jet pops out of thin air or perhaps all pedestrians look like Elvis Presley or some other rowdy effect...

*They always come with this confirmation message:*

[image]

Rockstar [chose to store them hashed](https://gtagmodding.com/sanandreas/cheats/), so due to collisions, in addition to the intended ones there are many other strings that trigger each cheat.

Therefore I propose to solve this [downside](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrXhYgVmKLQ)!

### Task

Write a full program that prints `CHEAT ACTIVATED` *if and only if* the last part of a string is a `cheat code`.

### Cheat codes

```
THUGSARMOURY
PROFESSIONALSKIT
NUTTERSTOYS
INEEDSOMEHELP
TURNUPTHEHEAT
TURNDOWNTHEHEAT
PLEASANTLYWARM
TOODAMNHOT
DULLDULLDAY
STAYINANDWATCHTV
CANTSEEWHEREIMGOING
TIMEJUSTFLIESBY
SPEEDITUP
SLOWITDOWN
ROUGHNEIGHBOURHOOD
STOPPICKINGONME
SURROUNDEDBYNUTTERS
TIMETOKICKASS
OLDSPEEDDEMON
DOUGHNUTHANDICAP
NOTFORPUBLICROADS
JUSTTRYANDSTOPME
WHERESTHEFUNERAL
CELEBRITYSTATUS
TRUEGRIME
ALLCARSGOBOOM
WHEELSONLYPLEASE
STICKLIKEGLUE
GOODBYECRUELWORLD
DONTTRYANDSTOPME
ALLDRIVERSARECRIMINALS
PINKISTHENEWCOOL
SOLONGASITSBLACK
FLYINGFISH
WHOATEALLTHEPIES
BUFFMEUP
LEANANDMEAN
BLUESUEDESHOES
ATTACKOFTHEVILLAGEPEOPLE
LIFESABEACH
ONLYHOMIESALLOWED
BETTERSTAYINDOORS
NINJATOWN
LOVECONQUERSALL
EVERYONEISPOOR
EVERYONEISRICH
CHITTYCHITTYBANGBANG
CJPHONEHOME
JUMPJET
IWANTTOHOVER
TOUCHMYCARYOUDIE
SPEEDFREAK
BUBBLECARS
NIGHTPROWLER
DONTBRINGONTHENIGHT
SCOTTISHSUMMER
SANDINMYEARS
KANGAROO
NOONECANHURTME
MANFROMATLANTIS
LETSGOBASEJUMPING
ROCKETMAN
IDOASIPLEASE
BRINGITON
STINGLIKEABEE
IAMNEVERHUNGRY
STATEOFEMERGENCY
CRAZYTOWN
TAKEACHILLPILL
FULLCLIP
IWANNADRIVEBY
GHOSTTOWN
HICKSVILLE
WANNABEINMYGANG
NOONECANSTOPUS
ROCKETMAYHEM
WORSHIPME
HELLOLADIES
ICANGOALLNIGHT
PROFESSIONALKILLER
NATURALTALENT
OHDUDE
FOURWHEELFUN
HITTHEROADJACK
ITSALLBULL
FLYINGTOSTUNT
MONSTERMASH
```

### Input

- A string \$s\$ over the alphabet:
  `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]`

### Output

- Print `CHEAT ACTIVATED` if there exists a `cheat code` \$c\$ such that \$c\$ is a [suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Suffix) of \$s\$
- Nothing otherwise

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

Comment: Was there a reason you chose to override the default decision problem output choices? It doesn't appear to add much beyond being cute. The rules also seem to require that the input be all capital, and not allowed to be lower case - this is abnormal and you should probably draw more attention to it if you decide to keep it.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes you've nailed it, I just like the idea of recreating the original reply of the game. I'm aware it adds _almost_ nothing, nevertheless it's suitable to some clever "recycling" of the part of the program that checks the input. For the second part I originally thought to allow all characters and make it case insensitive, then I saw that limit the input could only make the things easier and foster optimization. (I left out one cheat `18HOLES` because was the only one with digits) Beside being abnormal, show me what problem could it lead and I'm willing to change it

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Don't get me wrong, I've not justified a whim saying that it can be interesting to see how to handle that output. I really consider it can represent something different. Of course outside Code Golf this would only be a juxtaposition of a decision problem and the production of a specific string. And I totally agree that a good challenge is a dry one, one where everything is essential. But this doesn't want to be a default decision problem. And that output it's fundamental in it.

Comment: That is fine, I'd just like to say that I think it is unlikely your choices will improve the solutions that you receive. Generally, giving the golfer more freedom to choose I/O increases the quality of the responses you get, in addition to improving the chances you get of getting responses at all.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ok thanks, I'll try to leave as it is, if it didn't get many responses I'll know why ahahah - Never mind, it's an experiment :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>976</s>  965 bytes

*Saved 11 bytes thanks to @user202729*

Nothing fancy here. This is a hand-crafted regular expression which was randomly shuffled to please zlib and save a few more bytes.

```python
import zlib,base64,re
if re.search(zlib.decompress(base64.a85decode('''GaqK,9,=TU&D^"aoJ0#fKbc'=7=3*ZC@Sjrb9-nO,G4ij>guO6,*oNLi[tq[ZsOTo,XZG;oZsh/gQt)R:U?gtgs2QpS5&Cl,CM,c4B%`<W5ZEuN=Sb$f!,mP`%@TQ:&Dg(:q8*+N)Y?Q#F9kM'KZ&%\I2W`#7oOUp1-0Ge3]q_o8g@lWflG`*QMr*9[[`i?a`=U:auDF%8=66MDaNUUiPI8J#lO0\l@*E:%PS)VCHdD>/N`=l1`t*hVA<^ON+dhUtN/]3U\\tupZtkD$:DPFh-HW3PZ$AAiEFm(g;<YJ6I4"uMdQX16JBN/W.`>QFrON6O,^B%Jl3Mn<d^IObA<=$[b;g`-:O$Ga?$ch!SrhQNm;`Led6I;8/VCeIra;1&X%b)&*]\XB4+g3`FkTT#fc%HR8*)g95de$99CT;oVaps<Yn\im/BJu&A6-O8L3#Ha0p6]PKP2a7,,T6[K>'rQiC1R,U1_Ko/:-EAfrcS7ik6HfK>2:cMot]rkBY#!9d"ujd=<dn@]JT9h=mClIt.YL?*b"(ImA*!E/(\Gob*ghDs1dJ.;O"]CPGTo!=5g=9e2+caXT43.mu:*o8`ai!KoaLJ5',M&K[V8d'?J=ISEG?GUZMbWXJ[iCde,Mu[(,9nY8%-73jGpPZFWBXSOTGg5:U<P2"/=V(g[PZJodG+cZuag^64TE.>i4i"BRD8=mu,Jga5Ip(0Z34oicZ"d'bi@2Bqe/D6Y*)Cc-#tb7!E4Q']mZ0F2M]&qrpj]qLqg0MLln_4Q7QA[9<@I^3OJAJ)p1?+NpZH)nYYp(.J''*9mJUg?9h.]o72ZKgN)90W>0sIe(IqbdBCsfj<Ma5N''')).decode(),input()):print('CHEAT ACTIVATED')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVPJkqIKALu/rxhXFhEXFAFFRVAEBaQFFxCbVcQWQZbDvJ/vN13zUpUcktxSSX8X9@SFfX9HcZpkxa9/n5GLuE4e4AMkC/6Jbr@yAM0DJ/Pu4E@G@oGXxGkW5Dn4t4Y6xPDH9AMQAADeeW8QEqE1vcldq04idmu3jesB9IjGYIOd7x@ZS7ZfCsIPosc0LBUcgRN5G5nF2zRyRUuQk8GPEyO/d0K1gD4ofRYWYd5X0/2wyT4RVkK8waJhT45DY1nK9N6t3ypIvLMbc02lmlwIUm8CbsnQeabWVuSXBGyMZuMi9I92bZQoetprd/kAs96fCRHOn8fbk7dhVcpg0jTtaObYtE45JbdqEDSOS5wj63q0Ewix9lS6l@ccXlKN3R46sGufm3Zkm3727AK@H5jJVZFb/l0v5I6F6ZdLUaZG8cXVKW63urfXR2xn1BkmWq5iMBxPziIuDKql5KunHi4u5M4RtafqKlNkXEGui4b4xKTXxL8KistM6LrpjkO7TSl13pnVvXtln91VOR7b28DHhTHRObCBkDnjXvPUcKEmbF1Oi0ErxOzVl6bVbl5j/UHAUEj@malOkqw2Tg5Omk/Or0sUdxZi2WTwtkJssdra6aa4tdvs@s4IQTTc3EyBTI3Y3gei9z43SYdqL5lb5u1H0Re@vm2mfcqTksLKvhbnWoX0q@XDpyf@a26JGnmnY/YpFOh5O4PdKijEDFxZdsALn7hweOfyni@iY6VqsTteSyr0MKTJoN/ynJM2wNC4pOCEsJ2oskmcrTgEEKm5MQ@ED8xEWtgv@RmvG5J7PIlmxPoBIpUmiJCvM9Foj7AHn@6M1XFx2isaHw4pfbLrVzv0AQzNnSEmPt/yjNIJr/hAW6LTaBBVFx8cQcclIobOUEjBroENksgzqj7gRvP@4h10OPwMQ6zXrhXuqLIcqIAVG91VX7Ka7yx9WO/tO@xK2@frc6COVMYkJ3PhiikiI0Jpb9aSU2MNvc7nFERFAIDJWNTDGXlHrWTUNzahDJHd47SbCwEovF1/wea3x0RyhvKfQ0EQ@v@7ICR6pWUBQhCVZtGrAAF2vWS0XwyrCQdGW3IA9P19@gG7FjTt/FcXjMz/8D8)

Or [See the uncompressed regex](https://tio.run/##LZPHlqIIAADv@xVrJIgRREAxgSIoqQUDiE0UURBEOMz@fO/M271WHetV9qu4py/05ydKsjQv/v4njlzEdT4Bjv2V5dGrAP@Qjh94aZLlwecD/ic7DjH8A/0ABACAc95bhERoTW@y16qTCr3abet6AD2iUdhg5vtH7pLtl4xwWPSYhqWMI3Aq7SKzeJvGR9ZS5GRw49T43LuhWkBflD4Li/AzULP9sMnECCMiHrZs2JPj0FiVEr1367cKkih2Y66pVJMNQepNwC0JOs/U2pp8isDWaDYu/OBo10aprGf9do8LUOv9nRLhPD7eYs6GVTGHSdO0o5lj0zrllOy6QdA4LrKOpOuRwhNCLZZ7l3gOr6iGsocOzMZnp13JpuO@XcD3w2JylaWWf9cLqWuh@uVSlJlRPNk6xSrre3tzRBWjvlhEq3UChuPJWcB5rFqKvnrq48JS6h479lRd57KEy8h12RBiVHxN/Csvu4sJXTfdcWi3KbnOObO6d6/s87sqJWN7F/g4Pya6Bybgc2fcb54aLtSErctpibVC1F4/Na128xqbLwKGQvJ3pjpJMto4PTjZZ3J@XaKkuxTK5gJvy8QOrW2cXoZbylYZOCME0XBzOwVyNWL6X4je/96mXaq9Wtxybz@Knvjmtp0OKE9MCyt/Ls@1CulXy4dPT/zX3BI08k4nTMwXnfNuBrtVkE8WcGXVBS9c6sLhnf30faEzlqsWo3BaWqGHIU0Gg5bnnDQM7SQlBaeE7USVbershCGAiM2teSB8YCbQ/H7FzTjdEN3jSTAjxg8QsTRBhHydiUZ7hD64TDHWx@VpL2tcOKT0iTKodukDGJqKIaQ@1/KM0gmvOKatOtMIi6rLL5agkxIRQmfIZ2DPQLE08oyqD7jRfLB8B10WP8MQ47VrhTuqrDAVsBKjtx6IVvOdZw/rvXuHPXEXv74xdaQuTHIy56@oLCwEKOvPWlJmbKDX@ZyBHQEAYDIR9HBG3jtWOhoY21CCyN5x2vvwAci/XX/JfG6PiegMpd9DQVDn/7sg6OfnXw)

Comment: (I assume that you are more familiar with JavaScript, in that case (JavaScript doesn't have builtin for compression?) you can simply specify some language such as "JavaScript+<zlib library>". For demonstration purposes it isn't very hard to copy-paste the library source code into the header part.)

Comment: @user202729 Zlib would not be a problem in JS, but the most annoying point is that the OP wants a full program. The fact that Python has triple-quoted strings (thank you for the suggestion!) and easy-to-use base-85 encoding are 2 other good reasons to stick to that language.

Comment: (about match) Ok, I misread the statement...

Comment: How have you crafted the regular expression?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate No automated process here. Just some manual attempts of reasonable optimizations. Each of them was tested individually to see if it was really improving the zlib compression. It's probably far from optimal.

Comment: - I ask to you because of your huge experience - Do you think the production of the output has to be always fundamentally separated from the decision problem part? Maybe this challenge is an awkward example due to disproportion of the two parts... What can be said more in general?

Comment: @DomenicoModica The whole point of a decision problem challenge is to output either _true_ or _false_, no matter the nature of the task. Given the background story of this question, asking to output 'CHEAT ACTIVATED' instead (or nothing at all) makes some sense, so I don't really have a problem with that. But generally speaking, overriding the default rules (such as [this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/58563) and [these ones](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/58563)) is a bad idea. It's quite likely to decrease the number of answers to your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the references! I opted for a complete program to safeguard the compression part of the challenge. Am I right? A function that take only the input string would bypass the compression. I'll add its tag.

Comment: @DomenicoModica I'm not sure to understand your point about the compression. It all depends on the language used anyway. That's why you should not make any assumption like that and just let the people decide.

Comment: If you also compress the program is it shorter or longer?

Comment: @l4m2 I didn't try, but it usually leads to a longer result because the character set is enlarged, while the code is too short to contain enough compressible patterns.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Let's say I didn't ask for a complete program and a golfer uses a language that has functions. He can code the array of cheats in plaintext without worrying that would cost anything (in terms of byte count) because this array can exist outside of the function. (The function would only refer to that array in order to do the task). This is what I thought, I wanted the compression of the cheats to be part of the challenge, too...

Comment: @DomenicoModica If static data or other helper functions are defined outside the main function, it must definitely be counted in the total byte score. Doing otherwise would be blatant cheating.

Comment: Aaaah now it's clear, I was in the dark about this and presuming that in function submissions only the function itself is considered in the count. Is it too late to change my request?

Comment: @DomenicoModica I'm afraid it might be a bit too late for that challenge, but keep that it mind for the next ones. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 753 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•ćÉÞû9‚2¬ú@iH°<]ĆA~Qò†ø‚”Kƒćž»”‚ŸǝD6øZ\§HÔØΔÚÿþjvĀ¤¼§….[Ωîužć“₅nÕbn`ιwU0›•#`’ÿ¨¥€´y ‡ªsíÃ ÝæÿŠ… i‚Û€ä€Ô ‹‡€¾€€š¢ ‹‡„‹€€š¢ À®ly©Ã …«Â£…ß ÿ‚Ž ‹€€†€ƒ‰Ï…Û ÏÏ€È‚Ã›Î…ì €º‚‰f´‹€‹ ŠÍ€•€¾ ¥€€•„‹ À¸ÿ€´Â° ‹®â¢€‰€á á€€‹Ýæÿ €º€„»áí„ „ÏŠÍ«™n ÿÝæ‡´i¦§ €–€‡‚Æ¶¨ ‚‰‡Ü€ƒ‹®€á ‚Ãs€€¼§ ¨À‡‚ ‰¦ÿ €Ÿˆ™‚œÒÞ ¯š€É‚µ ©ß€èÿ ‚¿Þ¡ÿ‚ï ¬Í‡Ü€ƒ‹®€á €Ÿ¢ž€™žÜs ™Å€ˆ€€€¢îÁ ¸•ÿ®ísƒÏ °ä•Ç €Ðâì€Ÿ€€Èšs Ó´f€á€¾ ÞŸ€ƒ‹ˆ ‡—ÿŠë œÆ€‚€€™¨‚… ‚ìsaˆÁ €É€¨€ˆï¶ …ç‹€¹¶s ÿ‰à „Î¡¤ÿ€Ÿ ŽÇ€ˆ—‹ ŽÇ€ˆ›Í c•»tyc•»ty±»±» cjƒ¿€¨ ïÅ³• iƒ¾€„h‚Š ›ä€¯ƒ´€î—Ç ŠÍÿ Íˆˆ™ †æˆ×ÿ ¬ÍîŸ€‰€€†æ µ±Ž€ ³Ö€†€¯ÖÇ ÿ €¸€µ€©»å€á …Ž€šÿ ´Û‚œŠàëÌ ÕÕ…Ž i€·€œi‚µ îŸ€•€‰ st±µ€èaÍÝ i€Ü‚ÒàŠ ‚‹€‚™‰ ©„‰à ƒ¶acŽÏ¼Ã ‚è¡¹ iÅËˆ¬€‹ ·ä‰à ÿ´™e ÅË€ï€†€¯³£ €¸€µ€©‹®€ª ÕÕ€¿ÿ º°€á Ÿ™£Í i€©‚œ€Ÿ†æ ‡ªÃ½ ˆÃ¼Î ŠçÞ® †ì¦³ˆ¦ •»€€†â—É €ç€ŸÅÍ °ä€„ÿ ±¹mÌ¢’u#Å¿à‘Ç¥Ù‡‘×
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bVRbTxtnEP0rn5T3qOpDpUp9aNVGDYKXqo0q9SKFoER11NIHJ614qbZc7KDGuDImAQcc7wK2CcY2xRBfgi3N8dIHS/yI/SP0zKwNVVUJ1t/ON5dzZs7sz8nZB4mHV1e3Iy8YprGKInofRl7hfamh@3HirjQ/@n6Y@uS3L/BX5JXQ5lXk7Uxf5IbpsC89nmkJ23/vfPYB2t98J5W7yGPzMo8CBug//mXoyZ68k0rklW9/e3mA@tOwP0xH3na0uDKPjQfz9y87v957L/K6BHDrfuRtYSBV2Y8Wa9JacJHny5skjrDksIMyBmGJmVyCRfGKPtjTR55@HbpqUJ8P/oW@BBOrV9TDjRme1H9ckAMmZTI5xKLs8oDXDgNlc@6u/cmZz4tc5DWRVZ9XDlmeWPSZYlgicKzpRc1p9a71p/lIWuMUXseFJWTsGBg@Z@TGBoOmgNosrZSJpanlpY5AAvNqajXfwZ@EdeJWjAuqpSg9@DjigbFFZLWkHEbLwTwpqbf2sZWQslScBazb01cKKTmTqotx04TtMWFCiAsbz2RcXEfppAovDuZdU8ZQwvYoxYrawHXkUHTSCBUyVmmSU8d@v9bXqrrTMkBRfGs4Go5qy/x/cU0sQWhjXeYvtpOOB6zQwIJxSwgsQB2/O6FAAyqojqPkRQ5ZJ01KhKa0ZsKfCGAyaMdReBb6SYd1aT2ycvGAULR7wzFKOaOaV@nh0JGbFWW74tLLgVSteWVrVC05O0oRSEyc6aqGEw05U7GhEutCOnKWNLk1UbKZrYkveyaCsO3Cc6Rjfl7eJHTz3kXGzZGR9J4sTH7lWHr67@YeX@TEhFR1aGBFTujhEjT2Y538oOPRgl3bHGnwqqVY60oxbVrlfJAZpWyaTpe@TPwvadUhoR73zlQZLwjKTk7lODznq5MTvLjeG2ngBZOOpapxcqqPA8p1fyKusgWGvhZocalVP4TBZuO5wwY2zIUrz8C36rmeiAV1DWW8Ji75hE04NY3NEumOxVBSHEsOJaNdmKxlwaTapCptB3UKbMXZ7BxbnZV39mkooMqhdFwCK/hjlJLx9jl5q5rSECqtxUQPnXposca/uMuJ7P6X@ETZ8iamxtNAiXdlvOWkREXtcsiJcQDbESvWOm0fRCzJueNQlgh0TWdW4S7VbVY17vgJsaontXEzpEAHvGq6rFg@Qs7E62HKUBTH0vkJz/nZ8bae3qJ6BuDXdhNp2ceWbcEmXl5dTX09NTPz5VdTn07PTE3f@Xzm3p1/AA) or [verify all the cheat-codes](https://tio.run/##bVRNbxtVFP0rT@q@QiyQkFiAxKISKxZsoEhNo1a4gnThliobNOTDbkQdI8cp1E1czyS1ncaxHeKk/mhs6R5PWFjKj5g/Es69b5wghJSM39x3P86599x5nF24n3lwdXU7CaJpHhuoYvRpElQ@lhaGn2fuSPez76e5L375Gn8lQQ19XiXB7lcXpWk@HsuIZ1ri/t@7X36C/rd3pXEHZfx5WUYFE4wf/TwNZF8@SCMJ6re/uzxA@2k8nuaTYCdZWV/C9v2le5eDZ998lARDArh1LwleYSJNeZustKS37JIglHdZHGHVYRd1TOIaM7kMi@I1fbCvjzL9BnTVoDEf/ItDiebWoKqHGzMCaf@4LAdMymRyiBXZ4wFvHCbK5txd@5MznxelJOiiqD6vHYo8sehzxbBK4NjUi5bT6kPrT/eh9NIUwcDFNRTsGBk@Z@RSg0FTQH2WVsrE0tXy0kYkkXl1tVroEM7DBr4VaUG1VGWEEEc8MLaKopaUw2QtWiIl9dY@9jJSl4azgC17hkohJ2fSdB43TdhJCROCL2w8s764jtJJE4EP5l1XUihxf5ZjRW3gFkqoOunEChkbNMmpY7/f6GtT3WmZoCqhNRwdR7UV/r@4JpYotrGu8Rc7WccD1mlgQd8SAovQxq9OKNCICmrjKHtRQtFJlxKhKa@Z8DsimAz6PgrP4zDrsCW9h1bODwhVuzccs5wzqmWVHg4duVlRtsuXXoukac2rW6Na2YVZjkA8caZrGk505EzFhobXhQzkLGty66JmM9uUUPZNBHHfxefIe35B2SR08z5EwS2SkYyeLM9/5VhG@u8WH12UxITUdOhgXU7o4TI0jr1OftDxaMGhbY50eNVTrG2lmDetcj4ozHI2TadLXyf@P2jVIaHte2eq9AuCupNTOY7P@erkBC@v90Y6eMmkqVQ1Tk71cUC5vp2Lq26BcagFelxq1Q9hsNl44bCNbXPhyjPwvXpuZbygrqGka@KyT9iEU9PYApHuWgwlxbGUUDPalflaVkyqXarSdlCnwFacLSyy1UX5YJ@GCpocysBlsI7fZjlJt8/Je9WUhlBpPSZ64NRDi3X@xV1OZO@/xOfKlneeGk8TJT6UdMtJiYra45AzaQDb4RVrnbYPIlbl3HEoqwS6qTNrcJfaNqsWd/yEWNWT2rgZUqQD3jBdNiwfIRf8epgyFMWxDH7CC352gldPb11d/QM).

**Explanation:**

```python
.•ćÉÞ...U0›•   # Push compressed string "stunt hem hicksv atlantis kangaroo wler freak quer ninja suede nga cruel glue grime dough ters neighb dulldull ters thugs"
 #             # Split it on spaces to a list
  `            # Pop and push all strings separated to the stack
’ÿ¨¥...mÌ¢’    # Push dictionary string "ÿarmoury professionalskit nutÿtoys ineedsomehelp turnuptheheat turndowntheheat pleasantlywarm toodamnhot ÿday stayinandwatchtv cantseewhereimgoing timejustfliesby speeditup slowitdown roughÿourhood stoppickingonme surroundedbynutÿ timetokickass oldspeeddemon ÿnuthandicap notforpublicroads justtryandstopme wheresthefuneral celebritystatus trueÿ allcarsgoboom wheelsonlyplease sticklikeÿ goodbyeÿworld donttryandstopme alldriversarecriminals pinkisthenewcool soloÿsitsblack flyingfish whoateallthepies buffmeup leanandmean blueÿshoes attackofthevillagepeople lifesabeach onlyhomeisallowed betterstayindoors ÿtown loveconÿall everyoneispoor everyoneisrich chittychittybangbang cjphonehome jumpjet iwanttohover touchmycaryoudie speedÿ bubblecars nightproÿ dontbringonthenight scottishsummer sandinmyears ÿ noonecanhurtme manfromÿ letsgobasejumping rocketman idoasiplease bringiton stinglikeabee iamveryhungry stateofemergency crazytown takeachillpill fullclip iwannadriveby ghosttown ÿille wannabeinmygang noonecanstopus rocketmayÿ worshipme helloladies icangoallnight professionalkiller naturaltalent ohdude fourwheelfun hittheroadjack itsallbull flyingtoÿ monstermash",
               # where the `ÿ` are automatically filled with the strings on the stack
 u             # Convert it to uppercase
  #            # Split it on spaces
   Å¿          # Check for each word whether the (implicit) input-string ends with it
               # (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
     à         # Check if any are truthy by taking the maximum
      ‘Ç¥Ù‡‘   # Push dictionary string "CHEAT ACTIVATED"
            ×  # Repeat the string the integer amount of times
               # (so once for truthy; and it becomes an empty string for falsey)
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how compressed string `.•ćÉÞ...U0›•` and dictionary strings `’ÿ¨¥...mÌ¢’` and `‘Ç¥Ù‡‘` work.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>1094</s> 1082 bytes

```
HE
g
Tg
y
ST
a
GO
b
TT
c
DO
d
IT
e
AS
f
LE
h
IN
i
AN
j
AR
k
LL
l
OU
m
RO
n
ES
o
ON
p
ER
q
ED
r
AT
s
HO
t
IC
u
jD
w
Al
x
ME
z
NIGHT
=
M`(THUGSkMmRY|PnFoSIpAL(SKe|KILhR)|(SURRmNDrBYNUcq|NUcqaOY|TIzTOKuKf|NOTFORPUBLunAD|CEhBReYasU|xDRIVqSkECRIMiAL|BEcqaAYidOR|BUBBhCk|SwiMYEk|MjFnMsLjTI)S|(DUlDUlDA|TIzJUaFLIoB|IAMNEVqHUNGR|asEOFEMqGENC|IWjNADRIVEB)Y|(aOPPuKibN|TRUEGRI|CJPHpEt|WORSHIP)z|(JUaT|dNc)RYwaOPz|NOpECj(aOPUS|HURTz)|iErSOzgLP|T(URN(UP|dWN)ygs|OODAMNtT|mCHMYCkYmDIE|AKEACHIlPIl)|PhfjTLYWkM|aAYiwWsCHTV|CjTSEEWgREIMbiG|S(PEr(FREAK|eUP)|LOWedWN|OLpGfeSBLACK|COcISHSUMMq)|RmGHNEIGHBmRtOD|OLDSPErDEMp|dUGHNUTHwuAP|WgRoyFUNqAL|xCkSbBOOM|(WgELSpLYPhf|auKLIKEGLU|IdfIPhf|aiGLIKEABE|OHDUD)E|bODBYECRUELWORLD|PiKISyNEWCOOL|FLYiG(TOaUNT|FISH)|WtsExyPIo|BUFFzUP|hjwzj|BLUoUroto|AcACKOFyVIlAGEPEOPh|LIFoABEACH|pLYtMIoxOWr|LOVECpQUqSx|EVqYpEIS(POOR|RuH)|(CHIcY){2}BjGBjG|JUMPJET|IWjcOtVq|=PnWhR|dNTBRibNy=|KjGkOO|hTSbBfEJUMPiG|nCKETM(j|AYgM)|BRiGep|(Gta|CRAZY)TOWN|NiJsOWN|FUlCLIP|HuKSVILh|WjNABEiMYGjG|glOLADIo|ujbx=|NsURALTAhNT|FmRWgELFUN|HeynADJACK|eSxBUl|MpaqMfH)$
0

1
CHEAT ACTIVATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVTLkqs2EN33V2SRVMEuyX4WAhqQERLRw4zuKh6P3@@xXWM7nW@/aTx1K0kVgpJEP8/p8zG7rPaT778k1Z/fa4QF@AXcwXmYQGXgDbyHKRQG3kF6mIFwMAeFsASpYQVCwxqEhQ0oBVswAXZgDewBHRzAaDgCWjgBFvABwsMZagMXkDlcYV3AJ4gt3KBFeICWVe3hBdo/E1@Hym3anY3U7cuDk0ehEtfMqJFqaVNKXLB2p4uPLOowPdHwmphIXj68aa7NnLTxpbFdyNR1LwrKcZnZWZycA90KK8cnt8HcynYlFGXIxiKu3o2lLGTZMt@Q@1y1ETfUrst9e1ZrL1NHSRG2wyOGOKMwKZU8ZCRFq3F8qoOuLE3OaEpsTxXqnGS/1mKIhlkaKZmYrrs2qzdN3gasrKR81NVHvFBvrKtllz4oYbee3vU0tfGTDR5cyBHz9WAcHNXB@kdKK/xw5rFQHfkkWJ2Ejt57nd4XZzKm4HwunnZ53cZ8E3eFRBINiryW205uU@qW87VXsd@0NJT92Z/z2o8pX3uH2C8syvZtVZFLOvxISouioVnoUlKmn3EYMupYzWcuUyJvKDdT6WoX2vaUkt1VtUaGMdvZiyn4z8KxkwLbI70Hvgu@/ryKjjjK4V4GfeL23/KNe8uMaSnpF6jcUUXOkCbXRskGKxVIvs/l82hVDUciQzJ1EYoU6c0UWWQkAypuoiqoWzXS3TX2uTGKShVXVeLNJGhPJSeaUn854@3eyQNjXZYPbt1y/flYU6bCIXwcLgcSUy7MlPex3IoKOzTdkpQsDxyXm0ic36WVh5vpP7glY8yPf4STuxFzIB5RctsME8leOVbCPZ/G9K/f/87WFT80Cm03Qj8wY2ou4xO9dPt@aRlwn1lmxv2FmnW1MYaWnpsyx8GAsdjnDfo2WZOIizYl/reaHSmpLhPKrfgWU28YGL0anYdvGba5kh3V18aNeWBo4GGGzOiKc1hsjRIF139dv91eSJ@DFcqL5dChnR0gYGCont15bkYDxDN3y8KW2uPk1M7r9Gf4FeA3yGsU/ieRezkWHovvrB1KmefgCtuaYCMMM6ii1JU3zjMCoIUTJdQYcYw2GqaKG5oF/26tzGuWif94@QaeKR46X@MQ8bkruMof@yIo9Vwick7S@/j1zoSuhgWvudBPZtc4ULsynBD0teGshVLsppOsVQMZWgzdkF1htPc2Cl04bzrWJj6LJkR0/B4F9/9L6R37yTgFaI12Hm0rXA2Dk8xyLDOk@qVtjq2kZmER1rEEcnaGTb/uOsvC4Zw0WijXsNR@DQ8WPD0sozkqZHc@Oi98YOueq/KmZgLaL@VkB73iTS3zJ@ys0U9uDNSAweqpTGgHaYrw@voKPMH1jzWAJZ6Y/gM)

[Verify all matches](https://tio.run/##XVbJcus4ErzXV8yhJ0K69cz9HUCyRMIEATYWK9inlm3Z2mxJlhRepvrbXycoO6ZnIrQEZaCWrMwsvy7P65fFz39O6j9@NkxPFJ/og0KkBdWO7ihGuqfK0QPpSEtSgR7JMK1IW1qTsrQh5WlLxtCOXKJn8o5eiAPtyVk6EHs6Elf0SirSiRpHZ9IlXWhT0RupHb1Tx/RJVtdNpB/U/TGJTarDtnv2g/Qvs33QB2UmoV1Kq83KT2USkvfPtnotBpvuj5I/Fm6QqD@jay/to1gXZ873qTCXF1VJyavCL4fFKcl75fXtMWy59LpbKyMF47Ia1g/OS5GKYlVuJbytu4G30m1mL93JbKKeBplUaZdfKue5SYuZ0ftCtOos3x6bZGsvixO7GXfHmm0per6xKmfjYjrIZOH6/tKu76xEn7j2WsqbvjnwWebOh0b300@ZIGyUB3s/9cMbLnyikQOXm3w5BWmSj59TWfNrcJ9Pppc4Sd5OUi8Pczv9eDqJcxXqOUd5LptuKLfDc6VZVMuqbPSu17up9KvHTTTDfNtJbvttfiqbeCvlJgbm@ZNn3d2tawmTnl8nM8@qlWXqp2LcfIk04syhflyGwqiyldLd69CE1HXHqfjnurGMMRbP/uwqnKwCglTcHeQh4W8pNm8X1Quy7D9myR4B/3u5DXeFc51M5k9swsEMqFAWl9bolmuTRD886vGndZ1/UgWLa6pUTVnuXFUMmGRiAxBNJf261eHD8rx0zsjMDOt6Et0i2SgzFDqV@fnE7x@93mPWs9knoFtt3j43Upi0T6/7817UPRpzs49bvVM19@z6lRg92yMvQBTUd@70/t3NXwHJLZeH39IxvAs4MBxYAzYHIvkLck2A@f0w/c@//yw2NV5yk7r@hmNmxr073x7lR/8yX3kMPBYezPj4Ie2m3jonqwhQHjlfwCxeypZjN9mIGp66qeBsvTzIpD4vpPTq92EaHQZj1zen/D1Lu9LoXppLG24hGMk8LBiMrlHD084ZVaH/y@bu/YfYU/LKRLXKCD37PAIMRprlB3Rzk0e8DO9F2kl3WBy7x2b6C/1K9C8qG1bxH6qM@lZFrn7@HDWrfOeSH6j3kEEI2lllQgvjwOgj@xDdEGAczFVwHTdseopgcOpjwzng@FShie/n3rAKyma@IjbFK78bF6lKxoxvNcCt1KCtstVcxUxmKnEls7nhTOfaaVtT1B3wDBGy5VDgUo8ydEw9BVBbx5wW3pW@OYxGGqRDcAhXly1iOAunyt7jkq24yu4ztjXGhvPglAqBrrznCsSHA1bui/qoT5eqp/96ky69U1WgXFb0Aw7kZMgxFh4AAmbBmA@VbLjwOg5oNSYkvFoIjipjSuVD7bKG8kVoyFmIKCOHaiOK@lISw9H/TzCozv5vasQbPctjmKNH6jxD6rWFslDRl7YoOONsrYKOVysgiA0QZZWhCgdSIBLO90CbstY6BtQoKs@pwxdBchwSVxwahzMqxlF4uAPWmi/tYdVAfByu6qPcWeM6xER0N8daKfjKrMyACtILWCT2RmVF0KhPZ39LuRssKEZbg8N4Qxbp3x69RmyoNcbh@lkoW@c3ZY/GEeRk@pIv6TnoFV2D6B6UTKPVKoRKMNsrr0bfpLxODOfxXLcbZDE3uJNBxzQzoTKi4@ILpYvxy0txJGS2WCyhfLlFJco7B@qgFpA7LwIU1Ck7865T0aAgHYBuzETA3HOpmfTejdYBtHXlMKwvVozJdQQ7wQ/7batM12XGftxmo67iuNDY54020Og2I7Txa6cY0@NNMygxm86IzffWG6huHJidzzegYXYjzHM8UXDurs4QfzeVCQhqf5c8NAw@X1cjeoVZmNG5QBXICNhholfo/u42bU7hyUIlo68ZtpHGdcE0g6RHgUBVlMcMlbmry@Gfm8yQIuVeRiJHVI61QZBwAME6FZq/AA)

This solution is based on the observation that many letter pairs repeat several times in different cheat codes. We can replace those common pairs with lowercase letters (since the input will be in all uppercase) before executing the main regex.

Common letter pairs were generated using [this program](https://tio.run/##dVS7juU2DP2WdDMpAuQDgkCWaEnXlOhI1BgKpkiKLbZJEQSYhv8@OfLsAJsihX0hXIo8PA///eWfr3/9@f7@w9sfT69vr2/PT7/@8tOPT68/P//f@/n9XdOI3bUio007m@zUe5bquB9ZrQ5Val1ldsuVKHQplIhP09HqODXh5PQ@Bbnq5/lkct1V5Xmht6lIcKUmUQuD@X7ctK5u5upquJz6pC/mcaUTXYka5RIl12iaCz1G150z9Q2XTsDIOk7rLFfWNdaajJgq5Zg2LJIwDs3lPLM/0ENqIeujoaoGCtv8ttbdW@VAlevdhMPdPFCRauFuOTQBX/butCq6SzvHxtk3caHbgqVtomANw4wbeAcJ@6jUHJsnpq1lnVhVBwa2QbFhqjlm71qPsomUdZG4S@V5Mwe0ClCcD4o8yCIW2iZ53OZLGgegq/8djX6h5Rds5RoKc8lLQztzPfJCVOnyImxdWGp0PWvf2PnDdoYGcc89AYU4JXRC/Qm2bRv7XghUA9TSqeDHNiDqgwL1JKhxqmgjO@68ZGYX6STBFsYZXnIbOZ9sbZakoCe6y0XBNvpw1nJAEIEYNdeH06Umywt5qb@NtQ2zEdaaAnn7icrvji2jt09ZdX68N1fjesw/zoQSzCTIVM4HqeUL9lJJ6N5gyeFTmdBgygiZPny1N3IH1t42piUPQMWkiMXFuLNIh5rLUIvR9Zd1L6ogr49SUNKXW2qZtC4fQOKaCKwDLDB3Gk0BqLi6NylOGYByB7u6jADdF9Rl@ib@IEWd5SAQ65sr7uFZ4U74o8blDxBMlhGuxUoaNbY7V0pIMgBFqn6ab@73eVOr7liCQKgTj@1Ioud83txUdzsIGYtJ4OxVn2DDvnSFuVfFRmu7uCj@XGoZENb@hDwTwc8QNOXlS3wsWNiFZSfECNxB0Q/qvv/aHGtEs4qUIDfqmKqapDAC2Y5I3wFBqmzJjJQhf4/lXtgY/baxdrmNrEA@cBcR7jBYcT39Cw)

Comment: Can't that map be used in any way to write CHEAT ACTIVATED as Cgs ACTIVsr?

Comment: @DomenicoModica Unfortunately no. The lowercase letters are never converted back to the uppercase pairs that they represent

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 744 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ú↓╒E╢≤3░ü(⌡▬α▲Kw~Eæ║aù≡╕↓╠ækîª♥J╠⌂ÿb╞╝ø└╫£φ├╡▌ê╔ê;y9¿¿¢Ö⌡D◘MB╡ú:¢▌BÇ!ÜÅ?╫-◙¥·╘hM┌ûoƒPå¢¿δ╓x╓7╤½{α█hè▄ΔZ∙╙d≥♀'ô▼╘[πCò"┬╦•ù,╫▀╚╟TεÿRD°ß£{♠╕~>G╧ÜG⌠é~F~⌐?Iê→LA╟αa°♦V╔xhU∟δ¶╧▀Dïîc╫►τ8üîÄ╠⌂○╣*i☻▌ƒç╥¿ÇàM H─▬½÷`bû>miWπ∞*ü\σ¶REuü╚∙╠K┌ΦîΣ╫←▒╜A+░Ñ@)nφ₧∞'i╤Su@↑⌂¥ynΓv█e-0y╧Å§∟8φ·k½▌↑ëK╡7╛ƒ └¥τ─~↕τ╫^sh<▀Ö¥4╟╔«▼»0┌▌ûÆ↨1ñFf┘ê▒}[d↔ätf,▀⌂qt‼≈Xⁿ←ìhà⌂ÇΦXDÿs═JéΔ♠ö╙═[═4○tºyBoz?e╔§▐Ñ│δ`♣m♠°⌐ñ▐b╙|I₧◙Çq╧WNÿ:hYⁿ╝Ö┤ Ö╟╗φW@‼¡Δ¥♥£<Mÿt·╛~Ö◘U3∞P♂πΩ○U÷₧ï↨75-]├╢▒║3#│‼8^7.♦▼2↨8├Fⁿ♥>º√√─Ö¥┌Æ☼;∙Δ;+ï♪≥àΔñö╢íhåhò╤7e╣D┼┌τ·▐\½N⌂se0░╖1NmQQChs╕ë╒┌≈Å■╓{]&§╦π◄▲┘#?◙èáK?A▲≤û}╥5V#(¢⌠ü,∟δ$:åΓ↑╟ΘΘ±○«╠j┐≈o,v♦ì9╜æ-K│↑♀fwß☻δA┐┼à◄?║H√╖¿Æ↨á░Ö╗╣ΩÄú╢Mé=Ä▌↔→a°◘^j►╡┐t'◄wΔh←▬╜δt♫¡ïù«○├α7♣G▼K]H┬>♥á»φ9öù|╜Δ╥Éï¬¡.╚øKôªRø─Ç╞╗}₧4◙|`▓íâM ╥╨uⁿYéΔß☻¶∟ëæ┤,á╔∞₧Hæ}♪↑ßvâúy[>lu7▌z╒sóÄO:L▬╦íDq§φiIΔ═ûδ▓^ff▒
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=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&i=ZZZZZTRUEGRIME%0ANOTREALLYANYTHING%0AATTACKOFTHEVILLAGEPEOPLE%0AIAMWHOATEALLTHEPIES&a=1&m=2)

It relies heavily on compressed string literals, and there's not too much interesting about it.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 1200 bytes

`s=>/(ALL(CARSGOBOOM|DRIVERSARECRIMINALS)|ATTACKOFTHEVILLAGEPEOPLE|BETTERSTAYINDOORS|BLUESUEDESHOES|BRINGITON|BUFFMEUP|CELEBRITYSTATUS|DOUGHNUTHANDICAP|DULLDULLDAY|EVERYONEIS(POOR|RICH)|FLYING(FISH|TOSTUNT)|FOURWHEELFUN|FULLCLIP|GOODBYECRUELWORLD|HELLOLADIES|HICKSVILLE|IAMNEVERHUNGRY|INEEDSOMEHELP|ITSALLBULL|IWAN(NADRIVEBY|TTOHOVER)|JUMPJET|KANGAROO|LEANANDMEAN|LIFESABEACH|LOVECONQUERSALL|MANFROMATLANTIS|MONSTERMASH|NATURALTALENT|NIGHTPROWLER|NOONECAN(HURTME|STOPUS)|NOTFORPUBLICROADS|NUTTERSTOYS|OHDUDE|OLDSPEEDDEMON|ONLYHOMIESALLOWED|PINKISTHENEWCOOL|PLEASANTLYWARM|PROFESSIONAL(KILLER|SKIT)|ROCKETMA(N|YHEM)|ROUGHNEIGHBOURHOOD|SCOTTISHSUMMER|SLOWITDOWN|SPEED(FREAK|ITUP)|STA(TEOFEMERGENCY|YINANDWATCHTV)|STI(CKLIKEGLUE|NGLIKEABEE)|SURROUNDEDBYNUTTERS|TAKEACHILLPILL|THUGSARMOURY|TIME(JUSTFLIESBY|TOKICKASS)|TOODAMNHOT|TOUCHMYCARYOUDIE|TURN(DOWN|UP)THEHEAT|WHERESTHEFUNERAL|WHOATEALLTHEPIES|(HITTHEROADJ|SOLONGASITSBL)ACK|((CHITTY){2}BANGB|WANNABEINMYG)ANG|(BUBBLEC|SANDINMYE)ARS|(CANTSEEWHEREIMGO|LETSGOBASEJUMP)ING|(CJPHONEHO|(DON|JUS)TTRYANDSTOP|STOPPICKINGON|TRUEGRI|WORSHIP)ME|(DONTBRINGONTHE|ICANGOALL)NIGHT|(IDOASI|WHEELSONLY)PLEASE|(CRAZY|GHOST|NINJA)TOWN)$/.test(s)?'CHEAT ACTIVATED':''`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVZNb9w2EL3Pr8ihgKVDHaCnooBbUNKsSC9FqiLphYoeEqTOR2HEQdbIpdPf7j5qPySt04N2JYofM2/evKe/3357u3/39dOXpx@//fz8/uZ5f/Pr60JZW9RqCK2vvO@kGcwdD0ENXA@mM07ZUIqKUdVbv4ma74y1quWefW9ZKo4Rs6MajWu8H4JUNnFI3HDQnvE4GNea6J1UabPpOPVSs2UMxxHLYgrS@NRql6JWrjG16qVJ1k6XGoURzOgdm1D02F8GU@tSNhbntcXGBC3Rh5hcxKBPw04z201yssH62ppeWu@bakQyie3OD7YRzdZ6qxqD8LSptyGnxGJU5/JpOrl2GMU45ib4jjG9FxMDcKqwqZidcoVTE07VKDF67bGslNvU9bccZatcqwbvxbJyyKnDn1iz4aAqVrUWi/m1d7@njDN27JTbDL5T0SoXTZDOuwBUO4XsHCAalI3KsoviTKtjP/id5UGcBy41gtFpiB1LiL5PKJbzceOHPlXW1INXTRCAO1XJj0G8blLD4m0TemTYME4T7@yofQdEEI/fcSO9cVsTUG/Hu9p7K6i2CojPjjs1dIIgkFAwHgQpthnAQcLWoAyDr7ccO1U4GTV3eSDXlxF6hQpp1ENC7SMy1SF1XV6IM01s/M7JFFSxGVhtAXrqS6Slisg4DTNbdvUoqD1g3alY63iXJ5ii3lqz5RbcE9fmW0DNeJUGnO4aBgWOIEhU21wFhNzjkqhTC7Z3CA3FNB0XtynEjQUWubp@C4aoAFgjAgdFtI@4TbXuRnTN6BN4JKiRK6b4ETFA06yigIsDZwjBR0YNMeBVZCCMsT6zr9Am4j4X6VaCtx7ECaBaZUu0mxRFnSeM5T8//VuBVJWAeg6ZGdeNbYkRKapUVZZrCbl5MMwlWlnQ0C4G5ikE07WZizF3uAqcaVqavLa@7TUopL0gdgf@hjLGYcROmUoTn3pkj7l4G9FA7WAEPRS06UsQLq@KU4PjX6ODcGrrkV858VQK03jkI1NThsyxcmIRVtaD@mOUVqN3QWp3q8oI9MofXl8/3e@fin3521WdQXyl6mjugFpz9cvV1fO7j/dvn@rHv@73N2@WhaMlHTMNaUF5WrUy5Vql/lik6SkX7vS8pjnNRaeFKtFB8GYS0iXewIQymRZcoonamdM0851eNgetcO@YvkPiae8zN2nVzHSpp/RCECiHNVcaZ1xylS5Emo7lx1TUd7YLmmt7KC2iN3Mz0gv1pcyZ1dHY7zueQ5cCRKv@QHvQwQSyB9BlZ9HJbGihwbS2Jvo/U6OFVtMLZaQXlkcTgTN/6ULZaXavbF6Lx2xjdOjuw@/U37jo3JSA5ugolC3n5DN0KT4HXk2KSUc1UFNQs1XQulGnV7TWYDoLSF58sjA6eczBYujCqWitKpn0J/V3dGj@IyvOnwGZH7NC09p0c1@tpJ4mnZigXcs2nfx9wubsxjQpyjR/dnZaqmaG@JTUwTDPIWe3oqO8IdfFZwKdle0A3VJtDt5HK5@mg8nS8ouEFlqf2Tt/URyJfPyOoYX7v7nef3n49FRc/fn5qiR69/h5//hwf/3w@KGYlfD6/aeHp/uv88irm19fvZ8fy/L64f7zh6eP5fN/)

Comment: It should be a complete program

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 996 bytes

```javascript
a=0n;process.argv[2].match(require(`zlib`).unzipSync(Buffer("\"T93)OC8m{J84WLB/+&GTui0kf`VU#jJp;3(nOUQ))1b/-^*.t&O'V58#/0;D$- /te\"l_)RiO<j]tu=ck_:{b,bL^?Gm'^`%I5M;I{g\\GA-\\kud?RvYIH8=nvGq|{S l-zt5?.(zt9thR%m.v=[|hJZW7^/1RYRTJ8+)_>V-k!)[c2y1Ra5];'BM+#+!n-2\\nl;libQ7NmmYjG*0$n=S;=<W)dm/(vF=Q'zuYjfx2p,OBrqGc%upq28Y65rxj`@+]P6@s^O#A9G==H*bCz3G'rNADJOFs{8k~8#8.&Y|1=soo(JS>iVRy?Gj})\"?t NCjVmoUUDo*B98e-`xYyA#X#El;vqDjJwNb8cE|~@N).v3TT{?Kk*M1zw`y:}{$\\DPj\\GVv0lgP;5satf1\"K}4G:Jc1xt]OXCu^$#u&4?NA:Od)v+!+'1=TrUBx2vfh'~HFyXZ1BzK4(Dh_-_';/A}:SxM` !3\"4qXIjrCu$]]r+$P,6_+PqH#IU9,><UJ4U#[wEb`<,f%X*dr<#2V_U\"BjiPA]En0Ls\\yt61u #m@3rm6e]NMBR_\\La.7|9^)uh/$Ef.w^7{mn;~ug\\w`3MDQPb$IR}_2A3qkc:V>rC9|xC/0g:_A'nuV<Q ugVj|`1<(]*a~.jFlp$'Mw[gDF<E]5I$tbg\\10'xvwUBeWBk8g2( XjBhu*Y(KK}Yzu}(,YY6.5TcF)u9'=M[Lb4^ /g#<P$$3*>i}.Y4]m$2e1@c\\>dAW?O`DdexO=jB$7!bJ'/|O:X,}]|qQ%zs;xVStjz[4~8?>\"m \"yR5 L+5)\\&(jZD6$<-<mb>^;j2<").map(n=>[a=a*95n+BigInt(n-32)]).map(n=>[(a>>=8n)%256n])))&&console.log('CHEAT ACTIVATED')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZNrl6lgAIX/ilFULlFkomJKGAa5NhpvdJFLFFK5@@tz5tv5vNfaaz37WdvWQ/1kepuDn3b3C@v3V@eyLnPw9qZ1OuG6twqnpIo7um@uUc86BhvPQrXbbmNoGB64t81heHVNVAiWS8tDoyA6KuYwqUo79xad/24LmWS8MQo22e1Sk8eQ3TowOdSVxn0MI4xMepbA/biEyBQNZbKMCKcjGd8C0d0cG2wk1lb9gDO389LdSBntWaXhIDMt1qQ6TPO@AqDBpwHYBovKIFSanzTnho3j4z6M7NI3n6rg6M0v@utBzMFDbvpYt36@32cZYqAMRi06ic3Lcnr7hk1N8koMdEplEKGThJJvbpoEwN0xf4D9967jKHYjkYVdbshw7De2cDJoWOf6yC1Q7OWFPKQkwTs2zFhwOJK0UqC8i619JNVe4eM0kyC@2OC4z4RRveUaiNflxZZUP93p7YuGaDyuPAjutN@jrWF5Iw@ulYb9xEC04ke6VVt29uOxuE8IRdpKaxflykMTqLZjwqNot85dgzZrj9dHF8PD3Gh0r3xtEx3idtaupecdBkDs2X/zyGF2t@ox1En3lwSIfj3zjVLLJC6@Kk2qwQyGgni@0uVL0gILk29JhOBG3li4kOFyjbw@69fJDyHcvvKouJ6n5wiT4Z@l4aWjRd5yIJo/Tpq2Vw1gVfWScC9VmCd7x0@oOS6myuy4lR9D03PN0NjUMjZJLDwWIuX5GEQFe9Pj1ZqbbZ8AuPoFIohAzkfOcwqW2u0IgzkAbR1/fxRnWLDOwLUlfp693x2XeQV/ws9ariP2ewbcHDznJJ87bs2SXPaqxcelmsmuSnMecQOZ7UeClWw/NIJF1YT@wu367gAjnfN0JdbZmko1Yd/4ayOyyCU8jwXrW9jSKxKNTGxhHSQU9OvrqdyCJ5pSlAJOjcw6FhQRrjNtG/lZJLOC2B4M5xLlzRNX8qoDkxbxYQJQXvDfFUkTF9ZF4mwBfn8zWkjmIZUmqaf6OPZjtxNzkYe@fZvmX3SlDKJOBESvAyrSTlIYAHHU/hELMJtmHaM8Y2ySjWJ/tzugLlee6pyeKFJuUtismq6Puukcian/Y1QvlznaxWIkVXBVDMPicXPvnvY7C9/tVyhS/azxowhfHTVlflQTEez397cpSvyw2WvX@GHtHw)

```javascript
a=0n;                                   // Init
process.argv[2]                         // Take Input
.match(                                 // Check
  require(`zlib`).unzipSync(            // Uncompress
    Buffer("...")                       // For each char
    .map(n=>[a=a*95n+BigInt(n-32)])     // Add info to a
    .map(n=>[(a>>=8n)%256n])       // and take bytes out
  )                       // [] convert BigInt to Number
)&&console.log('CHEAT ACTIVATED')       //Output
```

First time using Node for full program

Answer (score 1):

## C (Linux GCC)

### Count: 1584

```
void f(char*s){char c[][30]={"THUGSARMOURY","PROFESSIONALSKIT","NUTTERSTOYS","INEEDSOMEHELP","TURNUPTHEHEAT","TURNDOWNTHEHEAT","PLEASANTLYWARM","TOODAMNHOT","DULLDULLDAY","STAYINANDWATCHTV","CANTSEEWHEREIMGOING","TIMEJUSTFLIESBY","SPEEDITUP","SLOWITDOWN","ROUGHNEIGHBOURHOOD","STOPPICKINGONME","SURROUNDEDBYNUTTERS","TIMETOKICKASS","OLDSPEEDDEMON","DOUGHNUTHANDICAP","NOTFORPUBLICROADS","JUSTTRYANDSTOPME","WHERESTHEFUNERAL","CELEBRITYSTATUS","TRUEGRIME","ALLCARSGOBOOM","WHEELSONLYPLEASE","STICKLIKEGLUE","GOODBYECRUELWORLD","DONTTRYANDSTOPME","ALLDRIVERSARECRIMINALS","PINKISTHENEWCOOL","SOLONGASITSBLACK","FLYINGFISH","WHOATEALLTHEPIES","BUFFMEUP","LEANANDMEAN","BLUESUEDESHOES","ATTACKOFTHEVILLAGEPEOPLE","LIFESABEACH","ONLYHOMIESALLOWED","BETTERSTAYINDOORS","NINJATOWN","LOVECONQUERSALL","EVERYONEISPOOR","EVERYONEISRICH","CHITTYCHITTYBANGBANG","CJPHONEHOME","JUMPJET","IWANTTOHOVER","TOUCHMYCARYOUDIE","SPEEDFREAK","BUBBLECARS","NIGHTPROWLER","DONTBRINGONTHENIGHT","SCOTTISHSUMMER","SANDINMYEARS","KANGAROO","NOONECANHURTME","MANFROMATLANTIS","LETSGOBASEJUMPING","ROCKETMAN","IDOASIPLEASE","BRINGITON","STINGLIKEABEE","IAMNEVERHUNGRY","STATEOFEMERGENCY","CRAZYTOWN","TAKEACHILLPILL","FULLCLIP","IWANNADRIVEBY","GHOSTTOWN","HICKSVILLE","WANNABEINMYGANG","NOONECANSTOPUS","ROCKETMAYHEM","WORSHIPME","HELLOLADIES","ICANGOALLNIGHT","PROFESSIONALKILLER","NATURALTALENT","OHDUDE","FOURWHEELFUN","HITTHEROADJACK","ITSALLBULL","FLYINGTOSTUNT","MONSTERMASH"};for(int i=0,j=0,k=0;i<87;i++){j=strlen(c[i]);k=strlen(s);if(k<j||strncmp(s+(k-j),c[i],j))continue;printf("CHEAT ACTIVATED\n");}}
```

### Count w/out cheats themselves: 143

```
void f(char*s){for(int i=0,j=0,k=0;i<87;i++){j=strlen(c[i]);k=strlen(s);if(k<j||strncmp(s+(k-j),c[i],j))continue;printf("CHEAT ACTIVATED\n");}}
```

So if I wanted to improve mine, I'd need to find a better way to represent that data

Comment: [1544 bytes](https://ideone.com/z24Geo)

Comment: Why don't you use a single string with a delimiter rather than a list of separate strings? For example, the first part could  be `"THUGSARMOURY/PROFESSIONALSKIT/NUTTERSTOYS..."`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 823 bytes

```
`Ö„t aå¡ê*`pUè`(kÂžo|â‘(adjack|(g—¡|cŸzy|nˆja)Èu|fÒàg(‘Ð|t|f‰h)|Ü…hnÔAÌap|Ü‹(ç°GÊght|â2Øop´)|ÂlckÆøevÅNgepeop¤|¦fƒa¼a®|i(°n(nÃqveby|t‘—v€)|amšv€Ë¡ry|ÖÁoa¥night|tÑ¡ÞÑ|ã””lp)|æˆrQtÓƒ‰|n(å
…ys|otfŽèFŠÞads|ÇÊ¯n(Ë†´|¡op«)|Âxà¤¤|ightpžw¤r)|ÊµsvÅH|àP‰(Îr|poŽ)|è	wal(kÅHr|skŠ)|s(Ö-‰hsum´r|å€dbynÔjrs|áÊ‰kts½ack|pe‚(fœak|Ä¿)|t(…ee´rgcy|Ãà„d°t®tv|Å­ikeglue|Äikea¼e|áâ¶¨g´)|ÓqtÜµ|ÂnÛŒrs)|Î…hšighÞ€—od|goodbyecruelwŽld|b(ub½eÖÜ|Áªã §€ÇÔ|ãˆ
E|luàÂoƒ|uff´up)|jÔÍã­€…p´|fŒrØ‡Óô|c(jpÊÊÊà|Ê•yÖ’tyßAßA|e¤ßŠyÐa«|„t eØ€e‹goˆg)|è0b$ew¬ol|t(ruegÎX|‹e(j«tf¦ƒby|‘kick†s)|oo»mn—t|aê‚ZUpi¥|Ë¯‡Ú€y|Æ2myÖÝŒ¹e|¨n(Üµ|up)eÊ!)|ž×Fµ(n|y”m)|Ò „dÚ |§Êãà!»d|fªlc¦p|è "Ã§°rm|ÚŽ’rÚR|jumpjet|oldspe‚¸¶n|w(Æ¢ip´|„na¼ˆmyg„g|—ÂT¥epiƒ|â€ fÕal)|love¬nquÀ&¥|ohdu¸|Ê)oÓ©ƒ|(iº†i|Ø‡ls§)pÒ"e|a¥(ÖÜgoÞ¼|dãŽ€›e×Ëˆals)|ç9é»y|¤tsgoßPjuÛpg)$`u¹u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZPLTxtXFMbVt5JWNFVXUTcOiqpxpUpVdl26ooRN2xSClGbFYF8Ptsczwzygrs7Cb4wBFxsHR0CNDTY4kAcLiEhJVOk7fxg9E9mLmTvn3vN9v@/ctO7419dzvI2yH9F5iD6ffDfnzPJoTstw8XN0beIDNLUP9URaj2dIM9BBn@LY/ytHFmppPcq1gJLc4p6hocmb5FMSqwtR4j1UFixux3h9THfC1zWNj3GGwn2uf2ks@HLyPX76le3gXKqLZjzDVb5US1z51VCOkvUB4SiJko63Ol5SSsOZpVlcWlxS8zny0URnCfko6VnsyAOvoe/miLe5YOsYWqmwh89NMdXlJvHh12hjE23TkXZHqLm/@7yFElbJ0nh4Uz5Vch7ZfhINHk2izl094RGvcB2vpGINVZwT@qLrNNT7J/cwwOAzCvs46C5j4Mp6HReeWJgi7j345FOsatxwybHRkG@jG7eXsaGbwrYy5ZKXQT1Knsbb3wsxL8ji3CUefnwL@cR8TtClXenflyNXM76Hd2EAjkJRS2JPzxCX8V@UfA0Vhb@V7DVQiIv/kggrJ3Dm46W/RFzBi1RGGWagZMeYPApOFR57gNcYGdh4j39r0ZeELsTXBxbvYt31ZLEhCWJH/HEXeXTsBBm2LdJU3A2UuYyGmaB5LZjHOyXU94gLOOHDCI4ljBVuC3LUbv5MZsC9b7g4ZqNEQTKJ80ASSHObN6TghZxckRGQqVl3@SlWeIvPKa6lHa6///VCpk9yMqMtP8f7MfmTwoD3Uc/xpo5TCodXyda8wppho2aEqH@Yv4uCWsZz2xRGotfgxiPCmtLSOJWMj1CSIUIzk4pnUBW3to2rrIWOTzqfoPh41klhSBL7K9G0g7yQrd7Lig7@B@t4owgjmYqQmdjBpuL6nSihy51JXGgW5dDOio5WRLLgnQgJ52Nxcygo7uAqIXZPzDiO5GKMIuNcEmZnbpakUQMtl3emKR1knbTyyTYTXpg6LvHaomWNqzhIhcBQtiRK1LI5A2WD0OHiQwxFiQgvhdc2/1EkyU9u6WaUTHtJ4bm1GHD@W3FlLyQCXArYqC1X4JmUayn8i2qKwgRMLxQbdbg1rkhukhaGa9gyBG8pIZE1JLJdxR1hU9PNcFCOf/yCn@FKeA58Tyr3H6QD3nWM6N25AG@C6@vx2E@xxxOxR7GZicmZ2MTDqdn7M7HpX36bnf5j/H8)

### Explanation

```
`...`pUè`...`u¹u
`...`          u  // Compressed version of "CHEAT ACTIVATED"
     p            // Repeat the string
      Uè          // Number of matches of the regex on the input
        `...`u    // Compressed version of regex from the python solution
```

The [regex](https://tio.run/##LZPHlqIIAADv@xVrJIgRREAxgSIoqQUDiE0UURBEOMz@fO/M271WHetV9qu4py/05ydKsjQv/v4njlzEdT4Bjv2V5dGrAP@Qjh94aZLlwecD/ic7DjH8A/0ABACAc95bhERoTW@y16qTCr3abet6AD2iUdhg5vtH7pLtl4xwWPSYhqWMI3Aq7SKzeJvGR9ZS5GRw49T43LuhWkBflD4Li/AzULP9sMnECCMiHrZs2JPj0FiVEr1367cKkih2Y66pVJMNQepNwC0JOs/U2pp8isDWaDYu/OBo10aprGf9do8LUOv9nRLhPD7eYs6GVTGHSdO0o5lj0zrllOy6QdA4LrKOpOuRwhNCLZZ7l3gOr6iGsocOzMZnp13JpuO@XcD3w2JylaWWf9cLqWuh@uVSlJlRPNk6xSrre3tzRBWjvlhEq3UChuPJWcB5rFqKvnrq48JS6h479lRd57KEy8h12RBiVHxN/Csvu4sJXTfdcWi3KbnOObO6d6/s87sqJWN7F/g4Pya6Bybgc2fcb54aLtSErctpibVC1F4/Na128xqbLwKGQvJ3pjpJMto4PTjZZ3J@XaKkuxTK5gJvy8QOrW2cXoZbylYZOCME0XBzOwVyNWL6X4je/96mXaq9Wtxybz@Knvjmtp0OKE9MCyt/Ls@1CulXy4dPT/zX3BI08k4nTMwXnfNuBrtVkE8WcGXVBS9c6sLhnf30faEzlqsWo3BaWqGHIU0Gg5bnnDQM7SQlBaeE7USVbershCGAiM2teSB8YCbQ/H7FzTjdEN3jSTAjxg8QsTRBhHydiUZ7hD64TDHWx@VpL2tcOKT0iTKodukDGJqKIaQ@1/KM0gmvOKatOtMIi6rLL5agkxIRQmfIZ2DPQLE08oyqD7jRfLB8B10WP8MQ47VrhTuqrDAVsBKjtx6IVvOdZw/rvXuHPXEXv74xdaQuTHIy56@oLCwEKOvPWlJmbKDX@ZyBHQEAYDIR9HBG3jtWOhoY21CCyN5x2vvwAci/XX/JfG6PiegMpd9DQVDn/7sg6OfnXw) is from this [python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205275/91267)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, no compression, <s>1356</s> 1351 bytes

`` a=T=>~"THUGSARMOURY,PROFESSIONALSKIT,NUTTERSTOYS,INEEDSOMEHELP,TURNUPTHEHEAT,TURNDOWNTHEHEAT,PLEASANTLYWARM,TOODAMNHOT,DULLDULLDAY,STAYINANDWATCHTV,CANTSEEWHEREIMGOING,TIMEJUSTFLIESBY,SPEEDITUP,SLOWITDOWN,ROUGHNEIGHBOURHOOD,STOPPICKINGONME,SURROUNDEDBYNUTTERS,TIMETOKICKASS,OLDSPEEDDEMON,DOUGHNUTHANDICAP,NOTFORPUBLICROADS,JUSTTRYANDSTOPME,WHERESTHEFUNERAL,CELEBRITYSTATUS,TRUEGRIME,ALLCARSGOBOOM,WHEELSONLYPLEASE,STICKLIKEGLUE,GOODBYECRUELWORLD,DONTTRYANDSTOPME,ALLDRIVERSARECRIMINALS,PINKISTHENEWCOOL,SOLONGASITSBLACK,FLYINGFISH,WHOATEALLTHEPIES,BUFFMEUP,LEANANDMEAN,BLUESUEDESHOES,ATTACKOFTHEVILLAGEPEOPLE,LIFESABEACH,ONLYHOMIESALLOWED,BETTERSTAYINDOORS,NINJATOWN,LOVECONQUERSALL,EVERYONEISPOOR,EVERYONEISRICH,CHITTYCHITTYBANGBANG,CJPHONEHOME,JUMPJET,IWANTTOHOVER,TOUCHMYCARYOUDIE,SPEEDFREAK,BUBBLECARS,NIGHTPROWLER,DONTBRINGONTHENIGHT,SCOTTISHSUMMER,SANDINMYEARS,KANGAROO,NOONECANHURTME,MANFROMATLANTIS,LETSGOBASEJUMPING,ROCKETMAN,IDOASIPLEASE,BRINGITON,STINGLIKEABEE,IAMNEVERHUNGRY,STATEOFEMERGENCY,CRAZYTOWN,TAKEACHILLPILL,FULLCLIP,IWANNADRIVEBY,GHOSTTOWN,HICKSVILLE,WANNABEINMYGANG,NOONECANSTOPUS,ROCKETMAYHEM,WORSHIPME,HELLOLADIES,ICANGOALLNIGHT,PROFESSIONALKILLER,NATURALTALENT,OHDUDE,FOURWHEELFUN,HITTHEROADJACK,ITSALLBULL,FLYINGTOSTUNT,MONSTERMASH".split`,`.findIndex(E=>0<=T.indexOf(E)&T.indexOf(E)>=T.length-E.length)?"CHEAT ACTIVATED":"" ``

Attempted using `min<var<max` in the array callback, but that resulted fale positives.

Pretty straightforward otherwise; I preferred not to use compression; can't be shorter that way.

---

5 bytes spared by @KevinCruijssen and my reading to JS golfing.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all. Maybe something like this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1RC4IwFEb/StynDWw/oNBY69IWpGEXy0fRWYY5adLfX0mvfXDO04HvUb0rX7@6cVoOrrGhjQPFCWCBeZmlaM65UTpS2hCVP29lup@J1OGkv4nOjgjCj303MYiAC@@elmGckLBD4y/ddGfI@QaURkkLqcgUknAHK4BQu8G73ore3VjL4Drv3xlwvg4f "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") (the comment is not long enough to hold the whole string).

Comment: @Neil for the record, I tested with Deno and that one didn't let me create the function `a` without `var` that I left here out for brevity. But otherwise, `console.log(a("AAAAAAAAAATOODAMNHOT"))` works, for example.

Comment: Wait, sorry, there was an error indeed. Thanks

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, single-mark operator was fine but `0<=` is equivalent to `-1<`, not `1<` - zero-inclusion is crucial because with `indexOf` returns, 0 is perfectly valid.

Comment: I know you don't want to use compression but you can save 70 bytes by [getting rid of the commas](https://tio.run/##PYzBToQwFEV/xXRh2hg6ro3FEIZkWDjMoroxLl7gQaulj7TFERf@OjLJxLu659zkfsAXxDbYKWWeOlx7tYLSKv9l2sxDhDDSHJZToB5jtOTBxU@bjnNKGGKiJdYesYs0okE36Tn4eUpmA0gX6Ojsr3hyCBF8cst5e9VEHYzeUJJSMjlCag3fyTfIft7vdoOQvfVd7Tv85pXK7x8Vt0pLexFNzyuZ6GWaMJQQkQshbm2@zQ79kExWXYt4YuWhKvRNUer6tdDVnj0wtrbkIzmUjgYOnBX/0U2zL56Ph0YzIdY/) (this is an edited version so that the link fits in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 1322 bytes

```erlang
a(X)->lists:any(fun(I)->lists:suffix(I,X)end,string:split("THUGSARMOURY
PROFESSIONALSKIT
NUTTERSTOYS
INEEDSOMEHELP
TURNUPTHEHEAT
TURNDOWNTHEHEAT
PLEASANTLYWARM
TOODAMNHOT
DULLDULLDAY
STAYINANDWATCHTV
CANTSEEWHEREIMGOING
TIMEJUSTFLIESBY
SPEEDITUP
SLOWITDOWN
ROUGHNEIGHBOURHOOD
STOPPICKINGONME
SURROUNDEDBYNUTTERS
TIMETOKICKASS
OLDSPEEDDEMON
DOUGHNUTHANDICAP
NOTFORPUBLICROADS
JUSTTRYANDSTOPME
WHERESTHEFUNERAL
CELEBRITYSTATUS
TRUEGRIME
ALLCARSGOBOOM
WHEELSONLYPLEASE
STICKLIKEGLUE
GOODBYECRUELWORLD
DONTTRYANDSTOPME
ALLDRIVERSARECRIMINALS
PINKISTHENEWCOOL
SOLONGASITSBLACK
FLYINGFISH
WHOATEALLTHEPIES
BUFFMEUP
LEANANDMEAN
BLUESUEDESHOES
ATTACKOFTHEVILLAGEPEOPLE
LIFESABEACH
ONLYHOMIESALLOWED
BETTERSTAYINDOORS
NINJATOWN
LOVECONQUERSALL
EVERYONEISPOOR
EVERYONEISRICH
CHITTYCHITTYBANGBANG
CJPHONEHOME
JUMPJET
IWANTTOHOVER
TOUCHMYCARYOUDIE
SPEEDFREAK
BUBBLECARS
NIGHTPROWLER
DONTBRINGONTHENIGHT
SCOTTISHSUMMER
SANDINMYEARS
KANGAROO
NOONECANHURTME
MANFROMATLANTIS
LETSGOBASEJUMPING
ROCKETMAN
IDOASIPLEASE
BRINGITON
STINGLIKEABEE
IAMNEVERHUNGRY
STATEOFEMERGENCY
CRAZYTOWN
TAKEACHILLPILL
FULLCLIP
IWANNADRIVEBY
GHOSTTOWN
HICKSVILLE
WANNABEINMYGANG
NOONECANSTOPUS
ROCKETMAYHEM
WORSHIPME
HELLOLADIES
ICANGOALLNIGHT
PROFESSIONALKILLER
NATURALTALENT
OHDUDE
FOURWHEELFUN
HITTHEROADJACK
ITSALLBULL
FLYINGTOSTUNT
MONSTERMASH","
",all)).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVTbbhs3EH2frwj0JAF2P8APAbjL2SW1JGdLDq1siz4IrR0IUNXAUtD2693DdRykAlYCpeHMmXPR08v5ePl8/3T9/eX05fZKr8ftp939x/Ppers@HC//bp@/Xrb@@zfXr8/Pp3@2/u7T7unyx9319nK6fH64fjmfbtuNujoWk6PUvNCcZeBSvCQTyuSVUlXlXFSWQj4x2yKRHYeZtOZUZ3U4GV1PVg7p/TwHNsUkDcsBvUlFrInJiZKtIayPWaioWXwyyR6M9k4fqceVwnxwnNnHUXwaSX3kfS06BM@lw6UZMLzWmUqQg9c2lrLU0SX2o@uwiMM4NJd59v2EHpIiU6kZVcmy7ZZva629VSZUmVJIgl2bW46SyK4tqzrg872ZKYkOkufaBd9nMbZQg6V5QUEbhhkr8AIShpo4m0A9B@6y1wWrasXAXHnMmEomhN7kMkonEttFDkVSWFbmgFYBKviJx1CZRizULdzjdjhIDhbo0v9Ho5/N/hFbmYxCH33TkGafJt8QJT70IoGKBEmjKV5LF0w/0RCgwTj44oBCjDI6oX4G29TVYYgMqgGq6RTxQR0QlcqWixPUGFW0kQF3Hn0IZuSZBVtQ8PCS6dj0jtpmTiJ6orsc2FLHb85qDrAiECP5tDfa1AzyyL2kn2vbJgRirLUI5C0zKn84Zo/evfOqy9t7Z9LYHur3s0MJZjJkivOelfwB9lJx6J5hydq7uECDRar1/OarIbOZsHbXBW7yANToFLE4BNxppEPNZqjGaPuJSi@qIK/UGFFSmltSXLhdnoDEZBFYB1hgblezAlA0acgSjQYA8gXsajMCdG9Qm@mz9BMr6shbgVjfXLEO9wp3wh9pbP4AwUwe4WqsuJrGvOZKGUkGoJFTv1CfzS/LSq2aqQkCoWY8NCCJffDzyk0yq4OQsdEJnN3qHWxYmq4wd6vouG03Norfl2oGhLXfIS@O4WcI6nzzJf4sggRjm50QI3AHRd@o@/HfZmojMiWkBLlREzgpibPVMg2I9BoQpIqazEgZ8rdv7oWN0a@rbZfVyArkFXcR4QKDRVPc5m5Dm7vj@bzb/fT65/F02f762@7D/Uf6gNfpr4e/X063p@1xuzHf99600v8A)

Comment: Fine, but it should be a complete program and the output: `CHEAT ACTIVATED` / <null>